# ImportError: libcublas when loading dataset on Rstudio running Keras with Tensorflow GPU

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio, ubuntu-18.04

Ubuntu 18.04
Rstudio 3.4.4
Tensorflow 1.11.0

When I run `install_keras(tensorflow="gpu")`
all was good with the last few lines being:

```
tensorflow-gpu 1.11.0 has requirement setuptools<=39.1.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.4.3 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: keras, tensorflow-hub
Successfully installed keras-2.2.4 tensorflow-hub-0.1.1
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Installation complete.


Restarting R session...
```

I don't think the issues are related to what's coming next.
I loaded the IMDB dataset: `> imdb <- dataset_imdb(num_words = 10000)`
And these errors popped up:

```
Error: ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chubuntu/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/chubuntu/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/chubuntu/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/chubuntu/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/chubuntu/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas
```

I can load those dataset in keras with tensorflow without GPU.  So what could be wrong here?